# cURL is not working on live server

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send push notification in `IOS` using `PHP` and `cURL` but `curl` is not working on my live server although curl extension is enabled on server
here below is my notification file curl code!

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$message = "Test Notifcation";
$regId = $_REQUEST['device_id'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://examplemyserver.com/api/push.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$data = array(
        'deviceToken' => $regId,
        'title' => "send_notification",                 
        'message' => $message,
        'notification_id' => "test",
        'notification_title' => "test1",
        'notification_description' => "lorem",          
        'sent_date' => strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
);  


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
print_r(curl_error($ch));
$output = curl_exec($ch);       
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($output);

?>
```

whenever i try to run notification file with above code its took more then  30 second and display below error :

```
array(26) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(50) "http://examplemyserver.com/api/push.php"
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(0)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(0)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Curl error:

```
Failed to connect to examplemyserver.com port 80: Connection refused
```

Can you please suggest me what is the issue and what have I changed in server configuration ?

Comment: You'r connection is not established. Are you sure you are using `http` not `https` or the `URL` is working one.

Comment: yes i am using http and sure to URL is working

Comment: try  `telnet examplemyserver.com 80` from the server where you are running this file

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);`

before

`var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));`

If it still doesn't works, then make sure your `url` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you have a `firewall` setup on the server that is blocking connections to `*:80` - All connections to external servers' port 80.